# How to iterate and check conditions across previous rows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to compare values of a column in a pandas dataframe, check if the condition holds true, and if does then do the operation.

I have a date set as below:
df

```
    Index  P_max  P_max_ind  RSI
0       0    0.0          0    0
1       1    0.0          0    0
2       2    0.0          0    0
3       3   11.8          3   81
4       4    0.0          0    0
5       5    0.0          0    0
6       6   11.5          6   75
7       7    0.0          0    0
8       8   11.0          8   80
9       9    0.0          0    0
10     10   12.0         10   80
```

Below is the description of each column:

- Index = Just like a serial number
- P_max = Max value
- P_max_ind = index of the P_max value
- RSI = Relative strength of the P_max

I want to create two new columns Peak2 and RSI2 based on the below conditions:

1. For every non-zero P_max point, it should check the previous non-zero P_max point and check if current P_max is > previous P_max point.
2. A. If not satisfied then check if current P_max is > the non-zero P_max point before the previous P_max point
   B. If satisfied then check if RSI of the current non-zero P_max point is < the RSI of previous non-zero P_max point.
      i. If condition not satisfied, then go to point 2.A
      ii. If condition satisfied then create variables df.Peak2 with the value of the satisfied non-zero P_max point and df.RSI2 with corresponding RSI value of Peak2 point.

I have tried below code but it is not working:

```
from datetime import date
from nsepy import get_history
import pandas as pd
import csv
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import peakutils
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema

df = pd.read_excel('Test.xlsx', sheet_name='Test')
df['P_max'] = df['P_max'].replace(np.nan,0)
#df['P_max'] = df['P_max'].astype(np.int64)
df['P_max_ind'] = df['P_max_ind'].replace(np.nan,0)
df['P_max_ind'] = df['P_max_ind'].astype(np.int64)

i = 1

while i < len(df)-1:
    if df.P_max.shift(i)>0:
        if df.P_max > df.P_max.shift(i):
            if df.RSI > df.RSI.shift(i):
                df.Peak2 = df.P_max.shift(i)
                df.RSI2 = df.RSI.shift(i)
        else:
            i+1
```

The expected output looks like below:

```
    Index  P_max  P_max_ind  RSI  Peak2  RSI2
0       0    0.0          0    0    0.0     0
1       1    0.0          0    0    0.0     0
2       2    0.0          0    0    0.0     0
3       3   11.8          3   81    0.0     0
4       4    0.0          0    0    0.0     0
5       5    0.0          0    0    0.0     0
6       6   11.5          6   75    0.0     0
7       7    0.0          0    0    0.0     0
8       8   11.0          8   80    0.0     0
9       9    0.0          0    0    0.0     0
10     10   12.0         10   80   11.8    81
```

Can anyone help me develop the flow and logic of the code?

Thanks.

Comment: If after row 10 there would be a `P_max` greater than 12, it would get `Peak2` 12 and `RSI2` 80 right?

Comment: @Erfan - we don't need to check for after.. if all conditions fail for rows before then the value should be 0 for Peak2 and RSI2

Comment: My question was more to find out if you are only looking at the two highest values. So are you trying to get the `P_max` and `RSI` of the second highest value next to the highest value?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you can use the following, which will be much faster than your loop:

```
two_largest = df['P_max'].nlargest(2).to_numpy()

df.loc[df['P_max'] == two_largest[0], 'Peak2'] = df.loc[df['P_max'] == two_largest[1]]['P_max'].to_numpy()[0]
df.loc[df['P_max'] == two_largest[0], 'RSI2'] = df.loc[df['P_max'] == two_largest[1]]['RSI'].to_numpy()[0]

print(df.fillna(0))
    Index  P_max  P_max_ind  RSI  Peak2  RSI2
0       0    0.0          0    0    0.0   0.0
1       1    0.0          0    0    0.0   0.0
2       2    0.0          0    0    0.0   0.0
3       3   11.8          3   81    0.0   0.0
4       4    0.0          0    0    0.0   0.0
5       5    0.0          0    0    0.0   0.0
6       6   11.5          6   75    0.0   0.0
7       7    0.0          0    0    0.0   0.0
8       8   11.0          8   80    0.0   0.0
9       9    0.0          0    0    0.0   0.0
10     10   12.0         10   80   11.8  81.0
```

Comment: Actually, I am trying to compare the P_max values in reverse chronological order. And if current is > then any P_max point going in reverse chronological order, it needs to check for RSI condition and if that is matched then Peak2 and RSI value is generated, else the comparison is continued in the backward direction.